# how should I relate user models on django models.py

Tags: python, django

I want to add in my class the user who create and the user who modifies and it trought me an error, i tried so many ways, this is the last i try.

Is the correct method the one I'm using?

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf import settings

def userDefault():
return settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Ambito(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Ambito")
    usuarioCreacionAmbito = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="usuarioCreacionAmbito", default=userDefault)
    usuarioModificacionAmbito = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioModificacionAmbito", default=userDefault)
    fechaCreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fechaModificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.nombre

class Componentes(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ambito = models.ForeignKey(Ambito)
    obligatorio = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usuarioCreacionComponentes = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioCreacionComponentes", default=userDefault)
    #usuarioModificacionComponentes = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioModificacionComponentes", default=userDefault)
    fechaCreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fechaModificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.nombre

class Caracteristicas(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    componentes = models.ForeignKey(Componentes)
    usuarioCreacionCaracteristicas = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioCreacionCaracteristicas", default=userDefault)
    usuarioModificacionCaracteristicas = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioModificacionCaracteristicas", default=userDefault)
    fechaCreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fechaModificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.nombre

class Verificadores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    caracteristicas = models.ForeignKey(Caracteristicas)
    usuarioCreacionVerificadores = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioCreacionVerificadores", default=userDefault)
    usuarioModificacionVerificadores = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="usuarioModificacionVerificadores", default=userDefault)
    fechaCreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fechaModificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.nombre
```

and this is the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'auth.User'
```

**Maybe I explain it wrong, my goal is to set a user value whenever the user add something, I mean, when the user add a row on the database, automatically save the user who add the row as it follow:**

if I add a row with:

```
 name='Juan', last='perez'
```

then my models saves

```
 name='Juan', last='perez', user=userId
```

Comment: what you should try is to instead connecting it with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you should connect it with `User` model

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and use this

Comment: @abhishekgarg No, that is not the problem. Using AUTH_USER_MODEL as the FK is correct, using it as the default value is not.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are assigning settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL (which is 'auth.User' by default) as yout foreign keys default values.
The default value should be an integer (the pk of the related User model), or maybe a User instance, but 'auth.User' is what you are giving it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the return value from your `userDefault` function. As suselrd points out, it is "auth.User", which isn't a value suitable for use in a foreign key.

However the problem is deeper than what value you return: it is *impossible* in Django to write a function that does what you want. The function has no access to the current user: it can only get that from the `request` object, and there is absolutely no way to pass that from a default callable. Apart from anything else, models can be instantiated outside of requests - for instance in the shell, or in a management command - and what would the "current user" be there?

The only way to set the current user is to do it in your views.